# Converting a prompt-string into an integer

Tags: c++, prompt, cin

I am trying to issue a prompt to the terminal, which reads an integer, and returns that integer.

```
int prompt(string promptString) {
    int input = 0;
    cin >> promptString;
    input = promptString;
    return input;  
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need something more like this:

```
int prompt(string promptString) {
    int input = 0;
    cout << promptString;
    cin >> input;
    return input;  
}
```

Comment: You don't need the flush. Unless you turn it off, reading from `cin` flushes `cout`.

Comment: ah thanks, its a long time since i written this sort of code.